# strange quotation mark behavior

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I'm learning SQL using Wampserver, Crimson editor, and [the New Boston tutorials](http://youtu.be/P0zWopVbW4k). Nothing worked until I change quotation marks:

With SQL commands, regular 'single quotes' don't work, but `weird slanty quotes` do.

When using forms and `$_GET["name"];` only double quotes will work.

Any idea what is going on here? I use a British keyboard, but so does the video tutor, and he uses `$_GET['name'];` with single quotes.

EDIT: sample code:

```
if(isset($_GET["sortBy"])&&!empty($_GET["sortBy"]) ) // only works with "full" quotes
{   $sortBy         = $_GET["sortBy"]; 
    echo "sortBy works <br><br>";
}
$topTenResult = "SELECT  `name`,`intuition`,`bravery`,`romance` FROM  `scores` ORDER BY $sortBy DESC"; 
// does not work with default keyboard single quotes
```

Comment: Show us the code. You description references PHP code not MySQL as the tags suggest.

Comment: if(isset($_GET["sortBy"])&&!empty($_GET["sortBy"]) )
{ $sortBy   = $_GET["sortBy"]; 
 echo "sortBy works <br><br>";
}// this did not work until I changed to double quotes

Comment: $topTenResult  = "SELECT  `name`,`intuition`,`bravery`,`romance` FROM  `scores` ORDER BY $sortBy DESC"; // this did not work with the default keyboard single quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQL, single quotes mark strings.

In MySQL, back quotes mark 'delimited identifiers'.  These are names that are case-sensitive or collide with keywords.  The back quotes are unique to MySQL; MS SQL Server uses square brackets for the same job.  Both are non-standard extensions.

In Standard SQL, double quotes are used to mark delimited identifiers.  Some DBMS treat double quotes as marking strings unless put into a standard-compliant mode; some treat them as delimited identifiers automatically.

Answer (score 2):

That is a symptom of having nested quotes.

```
.... " ... $_GET["name"] ...
```

The above goes wrong becaus the $_GET is inside a double quoted string. So search a spurious double quote, that turns your code in errors.

Maybe syntax colouring helps (like in the NetBeans IDE, with nice PHP support).